# MonetDB COPY INTO java.lang.NoSuchMethodError with new JDBC 3.0 driver

Tags: java, pentaho, monetdb

I'm trying to do a **MonetDB "COPY INTO"** statement inside Pentaho 8.1 (JDK 1.8.0_282) with new **MonetDB JDBC 3.0 driver**, and I get this, error message:

**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.nio.CharBuffer.mark()Ljava/nio/CharBuffer;**

[image]

Everything works perfectly when I use **MonetDB JDBC driver 2.8** or even **2.29**. Does anyone know what is happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You also fell into the Java 8 vs Java 9 API break. This issue was fixed here: https://dev.monetdb.org/hg/monetdb-java/rev/5ddfc0aa7f0e You can either use Java 9+ to get rid of the error, or download the tip of MonetDB JDBC driver source and install it or just wait for the next release.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think I'll wait to the next release, just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in new release: monetdb-jdbc-3.1.jre8.jar
See  ChangeLog  at  https://www.monetdb.org/downloads/Java/

Comment: I tested this JAR and I still get this error in JVM 8 (282). Are you sure that this JAR solves the problem?